# c# chart control, vertical scrolling problems with zoom ["Stuck Scroll bar"]

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, scroll

I have a program with a large c# chart control. I am allowing zooming by allowing the user to select any area and it will zoom in. This all works fine. When I go to scroll horizontally this also works fine and very smooth. However when I try to scroll vertically the scroll bar wont move, the only thing I can do is use the up and down arrow keys on the scroll bar and that only gives either the very top of the graph or the very bottom of the graph I can't scroll to anything in between. Any ideas on what could be happening? Please let me know what additional information I can provide.
thanks!

Some of my properties:

- ChartArea

  - CursorX  & CursorY

    - AutoScroll = True
    - AxisType = Primary
    - IsUserEnabled = True
    - IsUserSelection = True

Comment: Which GUI framework (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET)? Which charting library (there are many)?

Comment: And which charting library are you using?

Comment: Just the one that comes with visual studio 2010 .Net Framework 4... not sure if that answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.

I needed to lower the value under

chartAreas.AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize

the values on my Y axis where much smaller then the ones on my X axis thus I had to have a smaller "SmallScrollMinSize" in order for scrolling to work appropriately.

I figured this out from this article

http://www.codeease.com/scrolling-stuck-in-microsoft-chart-control-2.html